# Network modelling using Netlogo

Tags: netlogo, social-networking

I am new in using NetLogo, so I hope you can help me with this code. 
I would like to build a network with two subnetwork, A and B, where A has `N` nodes and B `beta*N` nodes, where `beta=0.5`. Each network should be initialised with five fully connected nodes. I need to add a new node at a time, assuming that each has fixed out-degree k. Once a new node `i` comes into the network, it links to a randomly selected target node `j`. The other remaining k-1 nodes should be selected as following: with probability `p`, `i` should be linked  to a random node of `j`'s; with probability `1-p`, `i` should be connected to another randomly selected node in A. 
On the other hand, the nodes in B should be linked (directed link) to each node in A with probability `P`. `P` can vary from 0 to 1.

What I already tried is built the two networks with N and alpha*N nodes respectively. But, as I said, I am new in using NetLogo and I am finding many difficulties to build this network that should be really easy in a different programming language, I would be more familiar with.

```
; Global variables

breed [agents agent]
breed [bagents bagent]


to setup

  clear-all

  setup-agent
  setup-bagent

end

; Defining agents

to setup-agent
  set-default-shape turtles "person" ; agent shape
  create-agents n-of-agents ; # of agents
  [set size 2 ; agent size
    set color white
   setxy (random-xcor) (random-ycor)
  ]

  ; Random Network
  ask agents [create-link-with one-of other agents with [not link-neighbor? myself]
    ask links [set color white]

  ]

end

; Defining bagents

to setup-bagent
  set-default-shape turtles "circle" ; bagents shape
  set beta=0.5
  let n-of-bagents beta*n-of-agents
  create-bagents beta*n-of-agents ; # of bagents
  [set size 2 ; bagent size
    set color red
   setxy (random-xcor) (random-ycor)

  ; Network
  ask bagents [create-link-with one-of other bagents with [not link-neighbor? myself]
    ask links [set color yellow]
  ]

end


to go

end
```

I hope you can help me to understand how to build such a network in NetLogo.

Many thanks

Comment: Your description of the connection rules is a little confusing. What is j? And what do you mean by "follow". Also, do all A agents exist before making links, or only some? This makes a big difference because you say "add a new node", so the second node can only connect to the first node, then the third node has a choice of 2 nodes etc. Do all A nodes exist before B nodes start trying to connect?

Comment: Hi JenB. I just edited the post. By "follow" I mean a directed link to another node. Each network (A and B) is initialised with five fully connected nodes. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does what you said. I don't think it's actually what you want as your algorithm is much better but still somewhat confused. But hopefully this gets you on the correct path.

UPDATED to make one node add each `tick`

```
globals
[ beta
  prob
  k
]

breed [A-agents A-agent]
breed [B-agents B-agent]

to setup
  clear-all
  set beta 0.5
  set prob 0.2
  set k 3
  setup-A-seed
  setup-B-seed
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  add-A-node
  if random-float 1 < beta [add-B-node]
  tick
end

; Defining A seed network
to setup-A-seed
  create-A-agents 5
  [ set shape "person"
    set size 2
    set color white
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  ask A-agents
  [ create-links-to other A-agents
    [ set color white ]
  ]
end

; Defining B seed network
to setup-B-seed
  create-B-agents 5
  [ set shape "circle"
    set size 2
    set color red
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  ask B-agents
  [ create-links-to other B-agents
    [ set color yellow ]
  ]
end

to add-A-node
  create-A-agents 1
  [ set shape "person"
    set size 2
    set color white
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor

    let target one-of other A-agents ; target is j in description
    create-link-to target
    repeat k - 1
    [ let candidates (other [link-neighbors] of target) with [not link-neighbor? myself]
      ifelse random-float 1 < prob or not any? candidates
      [ create-link-to one-of other A-agents with [not link-neighbor? myself]
        [ set color white ]
      ]
      [ create-link-to one-of candidates
        [ set color white ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
end

to add-B-node
  create-B-agents 1
  [ set shape "circle"
    set size 2
    set color red
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor

    let thisB self
    ask A-agents
    [ if random-float 1 < prob
      [ create-link-from thisB
        [ set color yellow
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

Some of the NetLogo issues I noticed in your code:

- NetLogo does not use = for `set`
- you must have space around mathematical operators (or NetLogo will think it's part of the name)

Some of the things you need to think about in your algorithm:

- why do you have an initial B network if all Bs connect to each A with fixed probability?
- what do you do if the selected A doesn't have any edges to follow?

As general advice, don't try writing something this complicated in one piece. Create your seed networks with 5 fully connected nodes. Make that work. Then do network A and make that work. Then bring in B. This iterative building is important for all programming languages. It is particularly important when using a new language so that you only have to debug one or two errors at a time and you know where the bugs are.

Comment: Thank you for your help, JenB. And also for your advices. I got two errors in "create-A-agents num-A - 5" and in "ifelse random-float 1 < prob or not any? candidates", respectively.
. The first one expects a command; the second one says that it is an illegal number format. Do you know what they mean?

Comment: I just copied my code into a fresh NetLogo and got no errors. Did you copy or did you type? My guess is that you made a typing mistake, possibly incorrect white space, so I can't fix it without seeing your code. Try copying the whole thing into a new model.

Comment: Hi @JenB, I would have another question about the code: if I want to add a new node to an old one, chosen randomly with a certain probability, how could I do? It seems this network is only fully connected. From 5 nodes at the beginning, step by step (I need to run a simulation), I should add a new node and it should be connected to one or more nodes (e.g.. preferential attachment), and the graph should be directed. E.g., : I should be connected to a neighbour of j's with probability p; with 1-p I should be connected to another randomly selected node

Comment: I don't know why you think it's fully connected. I just ran the setup procedure and then typed `mean [count my-links] of A-agents` into the command center and got mean degree (for As) of 16.02.

Comment: I think there was something that went wrong, maybe a bug. I tried several times with a few nodes and it was fully connected. I forgot to delete the comment, after tried it again, and it was working. Sorry for the inconvenience and many thanks, JenB

Comment: Amended for one node each time step